# Get the last 30 unique days that had data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run a query that will retrieve the most recent 30 days that have data (not the last 30 days)

There are can be several rows for the same date (so can't use the limit 30)

My data has the following formatting:

```
date         count
2017-05-05    111
2017-05-05     78
2017-04-28     54
2017-01-11    124
```

Is there a way for me to add a `WHERE` clause to get the most recent 30 days with data?

Comment: What database are you using?  The answer could change depending on your answer.  Also, if you have multiple entries on the same day, do you want all entries for that day?

Comment: @ollie it is postgres, ill update the tags too

Comment: Please edit question to indicate you want last 30 unique "dates", and not records within the last 30 calendar days.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I correctly understand, though...

(this is for most recent 2 day):

```
with t(date, count) as(
    select '2017-05-05',     111 union all 
    select '2017-05-05',     78  union all 
    select '2017-04-28',     54  union all 
    select '2017-01-11',     124
)
select date from t group by date order by date desc limit 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tablename 
where datecolumn in (select TOP 30 max(datecolumn) from tablename group by datecolumn)
```

Comment: OP wants last 30 dates, not last 30 calendar days

Comment: How does this look now?

Answer (score -1):

If you want all rows, which has the same `date` as the last 30, distinct dates in your table, you can use the [`dense_rank()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
select   (t).*
from     (select t, dense_rank() over (order by date desc)
          from   t) s
where    dense_rank <= 30
```

or `IN`, with a sub-select:

```
select *
from   t
where  date in (select   distinct date
                from     t
                order by date desc
                limit    30)
```

http://rextester.com/ESDLIM64772